# Regex Named groups

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am currently trying to concat Two groups but my expression is failing.

Group One should contain 0-9 and a full stop as many times as it wishes. Group Two a to z with a plus sign as many time as it wishes. The HTML repeats it self about 300 times so i have only added Two examples. This will only match the first instance and no more.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim text = "<tr><td>123.456<script type=""text/javascript"">document.write("":""+hello)</script></td><td>some html</td><td>date time</td><td>person</td></tr><tr><td>567.789<script type=""text/javascript"">document.write("":""+world)</script></td><td>html</td><td>time date4</td><td>person</td></tr>"
        Dim rx As New Regex("<tr><td>(?<Number>[0-9.]+?)<script.+document\.write\("":""(?<Document>[a-z+]+?)\)</script>")

        For Each m As Match In rx.Matches(text)
            MsgBox(m.Groups(1).Value & vbNewLine & m.Groups(2).Value)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Using a posative lookahead seems to work in the test code. Still open to suggestions

    (?=<tr><td>(?<Number>[0-9.]+?)<script.+document\.write\("":""(?<Document>[a-z+]+?)\)</script>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the .+ after script is greedy. Changing it to .+? (not greedy) seems to do the trick.

[regex101 example](http://regex101.com/r/zU7iL6)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

A greedy operator is used in the regex `.+`. By using its non-greedy form: `.+?`, You'll get all the matches.

#### Regex

```
<tr><td>(?<Number>[0-9.]+?)<script.+?document\.write\("":""(?<Document>[a-z+]+?)\)</script>
```

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/eL1cP1